# Output an array of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of arrays, each having a series of list items, which I am logging with `console.log(jobsList);` The output is:

[image]

The variable `jobsList` is created by pushing a bunch of arrays created in a for loop like so:

```js
for (var i=0; i < teamList.length; i++ ) {
  jobDirectory.push(newJob);
} 
jobsList.push(jobDirectory);
```

We are then sorting the arrays by length like so:

```js
jobsList.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.length < b.length;
});
```

I need to output each array inside of an unordered list. The desired output is like so:

`<h3></h3><ul>//insert list items here</ul>`

This would be repeated for every top level array.

`$('.row').append(jobsList);` throws an error. How do I return all of the arrays inside an unordered list like above?

Comment: `h3` is not allowed inside `ul`. You should place it before your `h3`.

Comment: As a side note, you can't have anything but `<li>` elements as children of `<ul>`, so your `<h3>` will need a new home.

Comment: Can you post your full code here? And what error is occurring with it?

Comment: of course, that was a typo, but not important to this question

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann sure, Ill update

Comment: It is two nested loops. or a loop with a join()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `forEach` and `join` this way.

```
jobsList.forEach(function(e){

   $(".container").append("<ul>"+e.join("")+"</ul>");

});
```

Where `container` is the class of parent div of `ul`. If their is no parent of `ul` then use `body` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
for (var i in jobsList)
    $('.row').append($('<ul />').append(jobsList[i]));
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because `jobsList` is not an array of elements but an array of array of elements. This way you can add these arrays of elements one by one.

Comment: In the doc it says jquery accepts a list of elements

Comment: for (var i in jobsList) {
    $('.row').append('<ul>' + jobsList[i] + '</ul>');
  } results in comma separated list items

Comment: Does  `$('.row').append($('<ul />').append(jobsList[i]));` also work?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```
$.each(jobsList, function () {
    var $ul = $('<ul/>');
    var $row = $('.row');

    $.each(this, function () {
        $ul.append($(this));
    });

    $row.append('<h3>some title</h3>')
    $row.append($ul);
});
```

Comment: Had trouble with this, but I like using $.each. Error is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined